# Why Unboxing Object to long shows InvalidCastException?

Tags: c#, unboxing

I want to know why following shows an `InvalidCastException`:

```
Object obj = 9;
long num = (long)obj; //InvalidCastException
```

After searching on net I find out `Object` considers 9 as `Int` so `long` doesn't exactly match `Int`.
My question is why `Object` considers 9 as `Int` but not `short` or `long`?

Comment: This would work also: `long num = (int)obj;`

Answer (score 4):

Because `9` is an [`Int32` literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674(v=vs.71).aspx). To specify an `Int64` literal use

```
Object obj = 9L;
long num = (long)obj;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can actually make this work if you explicitly say that it's a long. Pure numbers are read as integers, unless there are decimal points.

```
Object obj = 9L;
long num = (long)obj;
```

The following will also result in an invalid cast exception:

```
Object obj = 9L;
int num = (int)obj; //InvalidCastException
```

Comment: Your 2nd example, did you mean to use `9L`?

Comment: Yes I did! Copy paste is ruining me.

Answer (score 0):

`int` is the default data type for non-decimal numeric literals, just as `double` is the default for decimal numeric literals.  You can force numeric literals to other types with appropriate suffixes.  You can use suffixes for `int` and `double` too but pretty much noone ever does.